# Using the JSON.Parse Reviver to transform an object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Would it be possible to use the reviver on the JSON.parse function in order to change the structure of the data being parsed?

For example, how can I parse the string below:

> `fruitString = "{"Apple":2,"Orange":4}";`

to the following object?

> ```
> fruitPrices: {
>      "Apple":{
>          "price": 2
>      },
>      "Orange":{
>          "price": 4
>      }
> }
> ```

What I've tried is:

> ```
> let fruitPrices = JSON.parse(fruitString, (key, value) => {
>                       return {key: {'price' => value}};
>                   });
> ```

But what I'm getting is:

```
>      fruitPrices:{
>         key:{
>            price:{
>               Apple:{
>                  key:{
>                     price:2
>                   }
>                }
>               Orange:{
>                  key:{
>                     price:4
>                   }
>                }
>             }
>           }
>        }
```

Please may you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you at all want to solve this with JSON.parse? Why not parse and then map to what you need? I think this should be the way to go

Comment: I am trying to understand how the reviver callback function works. If possible, I would prefer to map the data while parsing it without adding another step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it with a reviver:

```js
let fruitPrices = JSON.parse(
    fruitString,
    (key, value) => key === '' ? value : {price: value}
);
```

That check against empty string is caused by how the reviver walks through the object. The last iteration happens to take your final object and the key for that final check is always an empty string. We don't want to change anything in that final step, so we just return `value` there.

Comment: Thank you. I could not understand how the object is traversed but this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

No need to wrap with key.
https://jsbin.com/pajosorapa/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
var fruitString = "{\"Apple\":2,\"Orange\":4}";
var fruitPrices = JSON.parse(fruitString, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof(value) === 'number'){
    return { 'price': value };
  }

  return value;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(fruitPrices));
```

Comment: Thanks. This works given that the final value is a number.